# Azure B2C using password reset userflow token is getting expired and not able to login into application home page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

1. User is landed into Reset password screen.
2. User configured his application password through Azure B2C reset password userflow.
3. Application page is redirected and user is again asked to provide credentials

**Our requirement is** - User should land into the Application Dashboard/Home page directly after password is reset through reset password userflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce the issue and it is working fine for me. Please use the below setup for creating **Password Reset UserFlow** as I have done.

**Step 1**: Selected “Reset Password using email address” under local account.

[image]

**Step 2**: Did Application claim.

[image]

**Step 3**: Gave access token and id token for authentication for the application.

[image]

I have recorded my output in this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89tFF.jpg). Please check out this.